# Empty list items in the recycler view

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-recyclerview, retrofit

When the app launches, first 6 list items (that is contained in a screen and a half) out of 44 items are empty initially. Once I scroll down and then come up they are finally displayed. I want these lists to load as soon as app launches.

I have tried to resolve by adding

```
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

before setting the layoutmanager of the recyclerview. But later I found out that this serves someother purpose.

Here is the part of code -

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.DepList);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        DepAdapter dep = new DepAdapter();
        rv.setAdapter(dep);
    }
}
```

DepAdapter.java

```
public class DepAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DepAdapter.DepHolder> {

    String[] depName;
    String[] detail;
    int klm=0;

    public DepAdapter()
    {
        depName=new String[44];
        detail=new String[44];

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://data.police.uk/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonHolder jsonHolder = retrofit.create(JsonHolder.class);

        Call<List<FetchData>> call = jsonHolder.getDATA();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<FetchData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<FetchData>> call, Response<List<FetchData>> response) {

                if(!response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    System.out.println("Server Error");
                    return;
                }

                List<FetchData>  posts = response.body();

                for (FetchData fetchData : posts ){
                    depName[klm]=fetchData.getName();
                    detail[klm]=fetchData.getId();
                    klm++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<FetchData>> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("FAILED TO FETCH");
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DepHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_theme,viewGroup,false);

        return new DepHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DepHolder depHolder, int i) {

        String title = depName[i];
        String brief = detail[i];

        depHolder.head.setText(title);
        depHolder.text.setText(brief);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return depName.length;
    }

    public class DepHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView text,head;

        public DepHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgIcon=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            text=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            head=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.head);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/backbutton"
        android:onClick="backfromdep"
        android:id="@+id/backfromdep"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Search dep option here"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/DepList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>

list_theme.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kent Police"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/head"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kent Police"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to call the service method inside your Adapter constructor. Call it in your activity and then pass the results to your adapter

Comment: Is the call to Retrofit an asynchronous call?  Perhaps you have a race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some architectual problems (like you shouldn't be making a network request from an adapter and especially not in the constructor) but ignoring that to answer your actual question ....

When you want the recyclerview to refresh because there is new data to display in the adapter, you need to call one of the `notify` methods. [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged) would be the easiest to invalidate the entire list.

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<FetchData>> call, Response<List<FetchData>> response) {

    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        System.out.println("Server Error");
        return;
    }

    List<FetchData>  posts = response.body();

    for (FetchData fetchData : posts ) {
        depName[klm]=fetchData.getName();
        detail[klm]=fetchData.getId();
        klm++;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged(); // Trigger an update to the recyclerview this is attached to
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think he might still have a period of blank items if the the callback takes a while.  onCreateViewHolder will still be called before onresponse

Comment: Yes, I do have a period of like a second where all the 44 items are blank. Anyway to solve that as well?

Comment: Sure but this is getting out of scope of your question. In short, your adapter's `getItemCount` always returns 44 right now. It should return 0 until the data is ready.